# Which database to choose for storing and aggregating finance data?

Tags: tick-data, database, volume, cluster

I'm planing to store stock market data in realtime and aggregate ticks for draw volume based cluster graph. Something like this:

[image]

Every tick (or second) data will be grouped by period (1,5,10 minutes; 1,4,24 hours), type (buy, sell) and price; calculated sum of volumes. Result will be something like this:

```
[
  {timestamp: "2016/01/30 15:04:00", period: "1m", price: 123.45, buy: 2345, sell: 1998},
  {timestamp: "2016/01/30 15:04:00", period: "1m", price: 123.46, buy: 3111, sell: 1040},
  {timestamp: "2016/01/30 15:05:00", period: "1m", price: 123.46, buy: 1421, sell: 3475},
  {timestamp: "2016/01/30 15:05:00", period: "1m", price: 123.47, buy: 6056, sell: 9138},
]
```

For delivery ticks from stocks to db I will use nats (https://github.com/nats-io/gnatsd). Which database I can use for store and aggregate in realtime?

Comment: I am aware that some people use MongoDB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198100/mongodb-schema-design-for-stock-tick-database

Comment: what about KDB+ https://kx.com/kdb-plus-faq.php?

Answer (score 5):

check this out [Arctic](https://github.com/manahl/arctic/commit/31021e7728a077100857bcf01f139cd937e0bb82). It's a Man AHL developed Mango DB for store their financial time series. Claimed to be really good. But i haven't try myself.

Comment: Arctic is the python class for generation queries to MongoDB ? Something like ActiveRecord for relational databases, but special for finance?

Comment: I think it is similar. It's a framework that you could use python to store, query your data from MongoDB. and they did many work to tune the performance. I can't be certain because I didn't use it myself.

Answer (score 2):

As @Nicholas said in a comment KX/KDB+ is popular in finance for this purpose. Direct message passing and local aggregation on the machine may be the best method in this case IMO.

Comment: very proprietary andneed experts to work with +q, best to go for open source tech

Comment: KDB+ is extremely expensive - 6 figures per year and up. They do have a free version, but it's time-limited and strictly for non-commercial use. Any revenue generating activity if forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different databases out there, all specialized for different use cases. The main parts you should consider are:

1. Using a time series database, since they can handle timestamped data (e.g. ticks) more efficient than any SQL solution can by using bucketing and other methods.
2. Using a database with a good query language, for example to aggregate multiple values, calculating highs and lows etc.

Therefore, the best solution in my opinion currently out there would be [InfluxDB](https://influxdata.com/). Not only because the easy API for inserting and [querying data](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/data_exploration/), but also because of the whole stack of InfluxData.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Cassandra would be a good fit. It's a partitioned row store, where rows are organized into table using a partition key.

It is common use case to store time series data, you could simply use ticker and a period as partition key. Cassandra is optimized for writes and it's easily scaled, but you need at least 3 servers for it to run.

Comment: not specifically meant for time series, influxdb or timescale are more specific for this usecase